# Gitlab API not showing all attributes in build status of commit

Tags: api, curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am using simple `curl` command as given in gitlab documents, to [Post the build status to a commit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#post-the-build-status-to-a-commit) .

But in gitlab build status it only shows:

> "Pipeline #20 failed for abc....."

Even when I am passing "description", "target_url" attributes.

I have tried,

> curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9ko..." "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/statuses/18f3...?state=failed&description=my_decsription&target_url=http://example.org/link"

From `curl` output in terminal, it is successfully passing all attributes. But in gitlab build status it only shows,

> "Pipeline #20 failed for abc....." .

I want the output to be like,

> "Pipeline #20 failed for abc..... my_description http://example.org/link".
>   OR
>   Any other format which supports 'description' and 'target_url' attributes.

I searched on Internet but not succeed. I am using gitlab 8.16.
Is there something which I need to add/configure in gitlab?

**UPDATE:** 
Actually the "target_url" which I am specifying is appeared as a hyper-link on specific build number of Build tab. But not appearing where I want it.
"description" is not appearing anywhere.

Comment: It's a POST so command should/could be `curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9ko..." --data 'state=failed&description=my_decsription&target_url=http://example.org/link' "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/statuses/18f3..."`. Request will be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Also seems you are missing `id` and `sha` required parameters.

Comment: Sorry, semicolon is missing `/projects/:17/statuses/:18f3...`.

Comment: There is no need of colon(if we add colon there is 404 ERROR of "project not found / commit not found ". And the command you have posted in 1st comment is equivalent to my command, there is no change in output. Please also look at my Update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `target_url` parameter only influences the link you are sent to, when you click on a build status label (see image below). To show it you need to manually add it to `description` as well:

`curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXXX/statuses/67814f7489214e91738680b433679224993dc1c4?state=failed&name=some_label&description=some%20useful%20description_of_failure%20http://www.google.com&target_url=http://www.google.com"`

If you want to see the description you have to go into commit details and roll your mouse over build status label:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works with gitlab 15.2.2

```
generate_post_data()
{
  cat <<EOF
  {
    "description": "$DESCRIPTION",
    "name": "$JOB_IDENTIFIER",
    "state": "$STATUS",
    "target_url": "$TARGET_URL"
  }
EOF
}

curl \
--request POST "https://your-gitlab-url.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/statuses/${GIT_COMMIT}" \
--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--fail \
--data "$(generate_post_data)" \
--include
```